# How to install BBB without a (direct) Internet connection?

Tags: debian, apt

I am trying to install [BigBlueButton](http://bigbluebutton.org) 1.0 in Debian 9.

The server is in a DMZ that does not have firewall rules for a Internet connection, however the VM has an APT proxy configured, in `/etc/apt/conf.d/02proxy`:

```
Acquire::http { Proxy "http://proxy-apt.internal:3142"; };
```

It also can access an HTTP(S) SQUID proxy called `proxy.internal`.

I managed to hack my way, and convince the  Debian 9 dependencies to install the official BBB repositories in Debian 9, and following the official installation [instructions](http://docs.bigbluebutton.org/install/install.html#installing-bigbluebutton-10), do a:

```
sudo apt-get install bigbluebutton
```

However, the installations fails either when trying either to install `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` and when installing `bbb-record-core` it seems it hangs waiting for `ruby`gems.

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upon close inspection of `/var/lib/dpkg/info/ttf-mscorefonts-installer.postinst` it seems the package is a stub to get fonts from outside sources using `wget`:

```
167                     if ! wget --continue --tries=1 --connect-timeout=60 --read-timeout=300 $QUIET_ARG --directory-prefix . --no-directories --no-background --progress=dot:default $URLROOT$ff ; then
```

As for `bbb-record-core`, looking at `/var/lib/dpkg/info/bbb-record-core` it can be confirmed it is trying to install some ruby gems directly from the Internet and not from Debian packages:

```
34                 cd /usr/local/bigbluebutton/core
35 
36                 GEMS="builder bundler"
37                 for gem in $GEMS; do
38                         if ! gem list $gem | grep -q $gem; then
39                                 gem install $gem
40                         fi
41                 done
```

So, what can be said is that `wget` and `gem install` need to fetch additional data from the outside.

As for `wget`, the HTTP proxy can added to `/etc/wgetrc` as in:

```
https_proxy = http://proxy.internal:3128/
http_proxy = http://proxy.internal:3128/
```

As for `gem install` create a file called `/etc/gemrc` and add there:

```
http_proxy: http://proxy.internal:3128
```

Actually at the end of the day, one of the gems was already outdated, and the package `bbb-record-core` still did not install with the error:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::InstallError)
gem "streamio-ffmpeg" is not installed
```

So had also to edit `/usr/local/bigbluebutton/core/Gemfile` and change the line:

```
gem "streamio-ffmpeg", '2.0.0'
```

to:

```
gem "streamio-ffmpeg", '2.1.0'
```

After that was able to continue the process, with both `wget` and `gem install` getting their files using the proxy.